# Error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required

Tags: .net, smtp, google-workspace

My website runs on port 443 and I have purchased a G Suite email account from google with my own domain name. This is my c# code:

```
        SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "587");
        objSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;                      
        NetworkCredential NetCreds = new NetworkCredential("service@MyDomainName.com", "Pass");
        objSmtp.Credentials = NetCreds;
        objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            objSmtp.Send(objMail);                
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {                
            objSmtp.Send(objMail);                
        }
        finally
        {
            objMail.Dispose();
        }
```

I have enabled two-factor authentication and used the new generated password to authenticate. Also, I tried using a different port 465. No luck.

When I used my personal Gmail "@gmail.com" account with Allow Less Secure Apps set to ON, it worked fine. Now, after buying into the G Suite subscription I am having issues. I am getting the following error: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required."

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Hi Victor! Sign into your google account. If i'm correct there would be a "Suspicious login attempt" warning message/email. If you can confirm that it's you trying to access it, authorize the access. That should fix your issue if i'm correct.

Comment: Hi @Scircia, youre correct I received that warning the first time and accepted it. But that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Victor thanks for your response! Now we know the "Suspicious login attempt" isn't causing the issue because you have authorized the access. The only thing that i can think of is that Google expects a SSL connection.

We can do it in one of two ways. If you wish to keep using TLS you could set the property of SmtpClient to enable SSL by setting [EnableSsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_EnableSsl) to true.

```
SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "587");
objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
```

or set the port to 465

```
SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "465");
```

Hope this helps!